# UnrealIRCD codepage doesn't exists?

Tags: utf-8

I am trying to make utf8 codepage for my ircd server..

**unrealircd.conf**

```
listen  *:9999
{
    codepage "UTF8";
    options
    {
        ssl;
        clientsonly;
            cp_utf;
    };
};
```

I getting some errors:

```
unrealircd.conf Rehashing
-
Notice -- Loading IRCd configuration ..
-
Notice -- error: unrealircd.conf:177: Unknown directive 'listen::codepage'
-
Notice -- error: unrealircd.conf:182: Unknown class option 'cp_utf'
-
Notice -- error: 2 errors encountered
-
Notice -- error: IRCd configuration failed to pass testing
```

How can I set the utf8 ncoding on the server?

Answer (score 1):

The error message says your ircd doesn't understand those options.  Searching around, [it doesn't look like the standard unrealircd supports unicode](http://bugs.unrealircd.org/view.php?id=3719).  The only place they appear to show up is in some russian "[lineircd server](http://code.google.com/p/lineircd/)" version of unrealircd.